# Chart.js how to have polarArea chart with a missing segment

Tags: typescript, chart.js, primeng

Can you make polarArea chart in Chart.js have a missing segment like you can for doughnut chart:

[image]

by adding this to the options:

```
 rotation: -135,
 circumference: 270,
```

Here is work in progress you can fork and try: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-w9vuee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgauge-chart%2Fgauge-chart.component.ts

[image]